# storing value from radio button to database with looping

Tags: php, database, loops, random

I am trying now to get the value of every radio button to store in a database.
The trick is I'm using while loop to display the question and the choices.

Here is my code in displaying the questions and choices.

```
class questions{
        function __construct(){
            $db= new dbConnect();       
        }
        public function fetchRandom()
        {
            $qr=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questionaires INNER JOIN choices ON questionaires.q_id=choices.q_id WHERE RAND()<(SELECT ((10/COUNT(*))*10) FROM questionaires) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
            $c=0;
            echo "<table border='3' align='center' bordercolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <tr> 
            <th>Number:</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            </tr>";
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qr))
            {   
                $c++;
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $c . "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $row['question'] . "<br>";
                $ans_arr=array($row['choice_a'],$row['choice_b'],$row['choice_c'],$row['choice_d']);
                shuffle($ans_arr);
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans".$c."' value='".$ans_arr[0]."'>".$ans_arr[0]."</input><br>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans".$c."' value='".$ans_arr[1]."'>".$ans_arr[1]."</input><br>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans".$c."' value='".$ans_arr[2]."'>".$ans_arr[2]."</input><br>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans".$c."' value='".$ans_arr[3]."'>".$ans_arr[3]."</input><br>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
```

How can I store the answer of the user to database. Little help will be appreciated. Because I don't know how to code it from scratch. Thank you.

Comment: are you storing boolean value in database?

Comment: no, I am trying to store string

Comment: why are you not using Form , you can only get the values from input fields if form is submitted... simple use post method to get the values from form

Comment: I have a form.
<html>
<br>
<?php include("class_lib.php"); echo $_SESSION['applicant'].", please choose your answer. <br><br>";?>
<form method="post" action="exam_start.php">
<input type="submit" name="str" value="START" ></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT ANSWERS"></input>
<?phpif(isset($_POST['str']))
{
  $newQues = new questions();
$fetch_data=$newQues->fetchRandom();
}
if (isset($_POS['submit']))
{
$user_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
$name=$_SESSION['applicant'];
$newAnswersSubmit = new submitAns();
$put_data=$newInputdata->submit($user_id,$name);
}
?>
</form>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

This is simple code try to code something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Question 1</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="ques[ques1][ans1]" value="ans1" checked> Ans1
                        <input type="radio" name="ques[ques1][ans1]" value="ans2"> Ans2
                        <input type="radio" name="ques[ques1][ans1]" value="ans3"> Ans3
                        <input type="radio" name="ques[ques1][ans1]" value="ans4"> Ans4
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Question 1</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="ques[ques2][ans2]" value="ans1" checked> Ans1
                        <input type="radio" name="ques[ques2][ans2]" value="ans2"> Ans2
                        <input type="radio" name="ques[ques2][ans2]" value="ans3"> Ans3
                        <input type="radio" name="ques[ques2][ans2]" value="ans4"> Ans4
                    </td>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = $_POST['ques'];

    foreach ($data as $key => $ans) {
        echo 'Question :'. $key .' '. 'Answer :'. array_values($ans)[0].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you :).

Comment: Even I am displaying the questions randomly fro the database?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example you can manage it by adding id into the name or the unique value from db to identify question and answers. Just change the name with proper values.